# A distributed data layer caching system that fulfills all these criteria?

Tags: java, caching, nosql, distributed, distributed-computing

I need to select a distributed data layer caching system which can fulfill as these conditions.

**Must Have**

1. Caches should be run in a separate process and can be called via TCP/UDP. We are not willing to run the cache in the same JVM memory space where the web application currently runs.
2. Caches should be distributed across multiple cache servers to eliminate any single point of failure.
3. Serialization should be transparent in the majority of cases and shouldn't require developers to implement methods or interfaces for every single class that is to be cached.
4. Single API for all types of Cache. Developers should not need to learn multiple APIs to read/write different Object Trees.
5. Eventually consistent. To always be consistent is an expensive proposition, one that requires n phase commits to all the nodes in the cluster. We don't want such a complex system.
6. Fault tolerant aka Graceful Degradation. If the whole caching system goes down the application can still run though performance will understandably suffer under these circumstances.
7. Automatic Cache Eviction based on configurations like LRU and FIFO etc.
8. Open Source and Free. Having the source code definitely helps as our experiences with Solr and Active MQ have proved. We are willing to buy commercial support as we did with Solr but the software product itself must be free.
9. Dynamic cluster membership. The whole distributed cache cluster must not require restarts when any node is added or removed.
10. High Reliability. The caching solution should be reliable in the face of server and network issues and can handle data consistency issues that can arise from server or network failures, write races, etc.
11. Highly Performant. Imagine the cache ending up being even slower than Oracle!
12. Extra Marks if the Cache Server is Java based as this is what the Dev Team is most comfortable in.
13. High Availability of cache data. This means replicating the cache data across multiple nodes such that losing a single node doesn't mean losing all the cached data on that node. We plan to store Java Http Session Objects so that we get session failover as well.

**Nice to have**

1. Web Based console to monitor and manage all cache server nodes or at least an API through which we can create alerts and notifications.

Comment: The list of requirements above match exactly with Bruce Ritchie's requirement s at Jive Software. So I have kind of copy pasted a lot of these points from https://community.jivesoftware.com/blogs/jivespace/2010/07/28/the-jive-sbs-cache-redesign-part-2

It is interesting to note that Jive eventually used Voldemort for their caching needs. They basically modified Voldemort to work as a cache for them. The problem is we are a consulting shop. Clients request us to make do with as much Off the Shelf software as possible. So we wouldn't have the time or money to do what Jive did.

Comment: Here's an analysis of distributed key-value stores. Though technically not caches they can be used as such. http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the web console, you should be able to achieve this with most professional strength caches available.

I would start with terracotta, ehcache or hazelcast.

Here is a list of some of the best caches

http://www.java-sources.net/open-source/cache-solutions

Comment: Peter,
We have had pricing discussions with Terracotta/EhCache. The quotes we have received mean that we cannot afford it. Let me have a look at Hazelcast.

Comment: Since both products are open source, how much were you quoted out of interest. ;)

Comment: I am not privy to the conversation. But I have heard my development manager state this to be four k per vm.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a web solution, why not consider caching on web fragment level instead, and use Varnish - https://www.varnish-cache.org/ - to handle the caching?

The reason for this is simple, caching is hard, especially for important data.

Comment: From what I understand of Varnish it sits in front of the web server. Now the product I am working with is a web based Digital Asset Management solution where most static content is already cached via Akamai, but we still have scalability issues. This is because we have tons of asynchronous background jobs which call the db umpteen times to get anything done. So while a web accelerator may help a general purpose caching solution is really what we need so that we can apply it through the length and breadth of the product.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1st January 2014, I would say that the following two look most promising

1. [Hazel Cast Open Source Edition](http://www.hazelcast.org/)
2. [Project Voldermort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/)